# navigate over dockpanel apps

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 20.0.4 and I would like to know if there is a shortkey for navigating between the apps on the dock panel such as winkey+T on windows works. (it allows you to navigate between the current apps on the taskbar).

I know there is super+Q, but it seems not all the apps get numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is super+tab. But you can change it to whatever shortcut you want in Settings->Keyboard Shortcut->Navigation->Switch Applications or Switch Windows.